# php segmentation fault function call

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I am getting a segmentation fault when I call a method of an object.  The method is actually implemented in the base class, and I call the same method in a lot of different places in my site, but when I call it in this particular case I get a segmentation fault.

```
print "<p>\$picture=" . print_r($picture, true) . "</p>\n";
// apply any changes passed in parameters
if (method_exists($picture, 'postUpdate'))
    print "<p>object has a postUpdate method</p>\n";
else
    print "<p>object does not have a postUpdate method</p>\n";
$picture->postUpdate(true);
```

If I place an exit command immediately prior to calling postUpdate I see:

```
$picture=LegacyPicture Object ( [row:protected] => Array ( [idbr] => 0 [idir] => 20553 [idtype] => 0 [pictype] => 0 [picorder] => 0 [picname] => [picnameurl] => [idbppic] => 1 [piccaption] => [picd] => [picsd] => [picdate] => [picdesc] => [picprint] => 0 [picsoundname] => [picsoundnameurl] => [idbpsound] => 0 [used] => 0 [picpref] => 1 [filingref] => ) [changed:protected] => Array ( ) [table:Record:private] => tblBR [prime:Record:private] => idbr [needInsert:protected] => 1 )

object has a postUpdate method.
```

If I place an exit command in the very first line of the method postUpdate PHP gets a segmentation fault.  The method postUpdate just updates the contents of the object based upon $_POST.  There is no recursion.  The fault happens immediately.  What could go wrong in between calling the method and the very first line of code in the method that would cause a segmentation fault?  Running PHP Version 5.5.9 on Apache 2.4.7.

Answer (score 0):

I kept digging and found that the bug was in a routine called by the common method postUpdate which as a result of a typing error did introduce an infinite recursion.  So this is the same old segmentation fault.